# Console Program with classes and display integer only

Tags: console-application

I have a task where I need to use two classes where ValueInput{} class contains of two methods. Add and FetchValue where it will return the value.

Here are my codes:

```
public class ValueInput
{
    public void Add(char c)
    {
        c.ToString();
    }

    public string FetchValue()
    {
        char c = default(char);
        Add(c);

        return c.ToString();
    }

}

public class NumberInput
{
    // This should inherit the ValueInput and needs to ignore every characters and accept only integer.
    public static implicit operator ValueInput(NumberInput v)
    {
        int numberOnly, intOnly = 0;

        if(int.TryParse(v.ToString(), out numberOnly))
        {
            intOnly += Convert.ToInt16(v);
        }
        else
        {
            intOnly += 0;
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Here's my ClientInput where the execution happens

```
public class ClientInput
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ValueInput value = new NumberInput();
        value.Add('1');
        value.Add('j');
        value.Add('2');
        value.Add('3');
        Console.WriteLine(value.FetchValue());
    }
}
```

The expected result should be:

```
123 // which ignores the "j" or any other characters.
```

I'm having a problem and it says,

```
System.StackOverflowException // on the line of if(int.TryParse(v.ToString(), out numberOnly))
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You haven't shown us what `DigitalInput` is, which makes it harder to help. Please provide a [mcve]. Note that if `DigitalInput.ToString()` is throwing an exception, then you probably don't need half the other code... please make sure your example is *minimal* in that it doesn't contain anything it doesn't need to, and *complete* in that we can copy/paste/compile/run and see the problem.

Comment: Also note that your conversion just returns `v` - `numberOnly` and `intOnly` are ignored.

Comment: It should be, NumberInput sorry for my wrong typings. :(

Comment: No, that still doesn't compile. Rather than just making a tiny change, please take note of what I've asked for. The fact that the code doesn't compile shows that it's *not* that code that's causing the problem. We can't help with code we can't see.

Comment: It's all of the codes @JonSkeet . The main task is that, the codes inside the ClientInput is default and I need to use 2 classes which are the NumberInput(inside are the codes inheriting the ValueInput) & ValueInput(inside are two method, the FetchValue and the Add method).

Comment: It is clear why you are getting `StackOverflowException`. You attempt to return the parameter `v` from your `implicit operator ValueInput()` method, which causes the compiler to attempt to implicitly convert `v` from `NumberInput` to the actual required return type of `ValueInput`. But unfortunately, the rest of the code doesn't make any sense. You could return `new ValueInput()` instead, but it doesn't look like that'd do any good.

Comment: No, this isn't all the code. The code you've included *doesn't compile*. Look at your `Main` method: `Console.WriteLine(input.FetchValue());`. What is `input` here? Please be more considerate about wasting other people's time: make sure that the code you've provided compiles and demonstrates the problem before posting. And when you say "inside are the codes inheriting the ValueInput" - that doesn't make any sense, as you haven't shown any inheritance in the code you've provided. Are you just using the word "inheriting" incorrectly to mean "converting" or is this just not the right code?

Comment: And as noted in another comment, neither of your classes actually retain any state. What do you believe calling your `Add` method will actually achieve? I would try to just get your `ValueInput` class working usefully before you start worrying about `NumberInput`.

Comment: I use the `Add` to adds the given character to the current value. But it doesn't work on my code :(

Comment: I updated the `input` to `value` sorry, wrong typings again :( @JonSkeet

Comment: "I use the Add to adds the given character to the current value." That's not what it does though. You don't *have* a "current value" in your class, because it has no fields. As I said, get `ValueInput` working first, then you'll be in a better position to implement the conversion. Now would be a good time to start learning about unit testing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
return v;
```

The implicit conversion should return a `ValueInput`. However, the value you are returning is a `NumberInput`. The compiler sees and say "Oh an implicit conversion exists!" and calls the implicit conversion again. In this call, `v`, a `NumberInput` is again returned and the compiler tries to use the implicit conversion again and `v` is returned again and so on...

Since this is infinite recursion, a `StackOverflowException` occurred.

I also noticed that you did not make use of the local variables `numberOnly` and `intOnly`.

Based on the output you wanted, I think this might be what you need:

```
public class ValueInput
{
    protected List<char> list = new List<char>();
    public virtual void Add(char c)
    {
        list.Add(c);
    }
    public string FetchValue()
    {
        return list.Aggregate("", (x, y) => x + y.ToString());
    }
}

public class NumberInput: ValueInput
{
    public override void Add(char c) {
        if (Char.IsNumber(c)) {
            list.Add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

And your `Main` method would look like:

```
ValueInput value = new NumberInput();
value.Add('1');
value.Add('j');
value.Add('2');
value.Add('3');
Console.WriteLine(value.FetchValue());
```

Comment: _"You probably wanted to construct a ValueInput object"_ -- given the code shown, that can be done trivially. But the class has no fields, and the `Add()` method does nothing useful. So while we can say why the exception occurs, there's not really any way to make a _useful_ answer here.

Comment: I tried to return the intOnly but I'm having the problem which says "Cannot convert type 'int' to 'ValueInput'

Comment: @spidy787 Actually, do you know what you are trying to achieve with this code? What do you think the code will do if you returned an `int`?

Comment: This would make sense, other than the fact that the OP *claims* that the `StackOverflowException` occurs in the integer parsing. That could be the case if `NumberInput` overrides `ToString` in a way which *also* recurses inappropriately.

Comment: @Sweeper if I return the int, it will break the given inheritance since the public static implicit operator ValueInput(NumberInput v) is a implicit with type. I'll get error that says it can't convert from type to int.

Comment: @Sweeper, can I remove my own codes and just put the given method? will you help me after I do it? :(

Comment: @spidy787 There is no inheritance (at least you did not show any) in any of your classes. It seems like you just want a class to which only integers but not other characters can be added. If that's what you want, one class is enough. Don't overcomplicate things

Comment: If you don't mind, can I edit the codes and remove my own codes and can you help me to construct to get the final result? :(

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper, it is working but I really need to use this ValueInput value = new NumberInput(); :

Comment: Where the NumberInput(); inherits the ValueInput and overrides the `Add` method and ignored the non-numeric chars :(

Comment: @Sweeper I have a red squiggle inside the NumberInput: ValueInput. The `Add` and the `list` :(

Comment: @spidy787 Try it now. If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: There's no error @Sweeper but the result includes the character value :(

Comment: @spidy787 I can't reproduce. I got `123` as output. Try again. If it still does not work. I can't help you either.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake @Sweeper it's working now :) Thank you so much!

Comment: @spidy787 If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!